# centered text/equations inside align environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

is there a way to insert a centered line of text or mathematics inside an align-environment?

For example, in the code below, I'd like to have the `\vdots` between the equations above and below horizontally centered, completely ignoring the alignment markers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  f(1) &= 1 \\
  f(2) &= 2 \\
  \vdots & \\
  f(n) &= n f(n-1)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent X\hrulefill X
  \begin{align}
  f(1) &= 1 \\
  f(2) &= 2 \\
  \shortintertext{\hfil    \vdots \hfil}
  f(n) &= n f(n-1) xxxxxxx
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, apparently I wasn't clear enough when asking the question (I have edited it and added more details). What I want are vdots which are centered independently from all the alignment markers and the content which is above and below. With vdotswithin you have to choose a center point which depends on the alignment markers.

Comment: @r_faszanatas centered with respect to what? the text width?

Comment: @r_faszanatas Is it like the updated one? If not, I will delete this :-)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Bumping an old topic... Where is the macro \shortintertext defined?

Comment: @LucasSoares It is defined by `mathtools`. This leaves little tight vertical space compared to `\intertext` (which is defined by `amsmath`).

Answer (score 2):

The “official” way of doing this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  f(1) &= 1 \\
  f(2) &= 2 \\
       &\vdotswithin{=} \nonumber \\
  f(n) &= n f(n-1) xxxxxxx
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this doesn't answer the question, though. So… why would you like `\vdots` that ignore the content of `align` in a “text” line?

Comment: I'm well aware of the "official" way but in my case it was visually unappealing. I have a long chain of aligned equations $f(k)= ...$, just like in your example above, where the right hand side is very long and takes up about 90% of the column width. Vdots under the equal sign just don't look good to me in this case. An example for a centered text line would be something like \intertext{- using our convention that ... -}, which looks better centered than left justified. Again, "better" is of course highly subjective.